# Changing node structure during an animation

Tags: animation, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

After doing some quick research on animating nodes, all i could find was that you can animate values, but changing the structure was not addressed. I would like to change the order that i composite the layers in since the view changes necessitating this a rearrangement of the node structure. I know i can render select parts of the animation separately and restructure the nodes before doing the next segment, but if i could get it to do that on it's own I could render it all at once while i'm at school or asleep instead of checking in every hour or so to doctor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the two node setups you need. (the two versions) and use a Mix node to mix from one setup to the other. You can keyframe the factor to do that automatically.

Comment: Oh, so basically make all the structures i need and fade between each set as i need to?

Comment: Basically yes. There's probably a specific frame at which your rearrangement needs to take place. So you can keyframe from (e.g.) 0 to 1 from one frame to the next.

Comment: Actually no, a fade might be just what i need. I'm singling out a laser to add a glow effect to only the beam, and i switch the layering as the housing of the laser passes the beam, but the glow sudden disappears so a fade could doctor that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Great! Just another idea: you could also render the housing on a separate renderlayer and use that as a matte before the glow. That's probably the precisest way to achieve that.